# Move caption directly under the image when simultaneously using tikzpicture and minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I have some tikzpicture that contains minipage. It works as intended, however I am not able to move the caption directly under the image (the image itself is on the desired location). How to achieve this?

Minimalized example below:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                
                \node [
                above right,
                inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
                {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7.6cm]{example-image-duck}};
                
                \begin{scope}[
                    x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
                    y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
                    \draw[latex-, thick,blue,align=center] 
                    (4.1,6.35) -- (5.4,7.5)
                    node[right,blue,font=\small \bfseries]{1};
                    
                \end{scope}          
            \end{minipage}%
            
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \adjustbox{trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip}{\usebox0}
    \captionsetup{width=0.3\textwidth}
    \caption{Front}
    \label{1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I get is seen on picture below.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Move caption under the picture`, it *is* under the picture. But you haven't centered your float so the image is left aligned and the caption is the default centered. Try adding `\centering` just after `\begin{figure}[h!]`.

Comment: Note I'd use at least `\begin{figure}[htp!]`, just in case the float cannot be placed `here about`

Comment: Hi, the image itself is on the desired location, what I meant was that I want to move (put) the caption under the image

Comment: I made some edits in the post to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the intention of this code, but I think it's better to apply the `minipage` into the `figure` and not into the `tikzpicture`. This way the caption can also be inserted into the `minipage`

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}
%            \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
%                
                \node [
                above right,
                inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
                {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7.6cm]{example-image-duck}};
                
                \begin{scope}[
                    x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
                    y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
                    \draw[latex-, thick,blue,align=center] 
                    (4.1,6.35) -- (5.4,7.5)
                    node[right,blue,font=\small \bfseries]{1};
                    
                \end{scope}          
%            \end{minipage}%
%            
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \adjustbox{trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip, width=\textwidth, height=7.6cm}{\usebox0}
%    \captionsetup{width=0.3\textwidth}
    \caption{Front}
    \label{1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works as desired. I inserted some text on the right side of image (not shown in this question), which is why I used minipage in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation using two minipages and two saveboxes.

There are other ways to adjust the bounding box for a tikzpicture than `\adjustbox`.  You can use `\pgfinteruptboundingbox` to ignore certain steps.  You can use `\pgfresetboundingbox` and only include certain coordinates in a `\path` after.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
                
                \node [
                above right,
                inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
                {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7.6cm]{example-image-duck}};
                
                \begin{scope}[
                    x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
                    y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
                    \draw[latex-, thick,blue,align=center] 
                    (4.1,6.35) -- (5.4,7.5)
                    node[right,blue,font=\small \bfseries]{1};
                    
                \end{scope}          
            \end{minipage}%
            
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \sbox1{\adjustbox{trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip}{\usebox0}}% measure width
    \begin{minipage}{\wd1}
      \usebox1
      \caption{Front}
      \label{1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I finally checked this solution. It is working after I of course add \end{document} and after I change \width=\wd1 with just \wd1.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry about that.